# Logback/SLF4J - is there a configuration setting to prevent a stack trace being printed out?

Tags: testing, mocking, logback, stack-trace

In my app code I have a situation where I want an Exception to be fully printed out with the stack trace and everything.

In my testing code for this situation, when I deliberately `doThrow()`, to test the handling of this Exception, I want still to log to error, but without the stack trace, partly to prevent cluttering the log, partly to prevent the testing code wasting time printing a stack trace I have no need of.

Is there a way I can do this in my logback-test.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did find a workaround... but it's not for TDD purists.

In my app class under test (it could actually be some utility class and then be used by any app class) I put this:

```
private boolean printErrorStackTrace = true;
void setPrintErrorStackTrace( boolean doPrint ){
    printErrorStackTrace = doPrint;
}
```

Again in the app class I changed the LOGGER line from this

```
LOGGER.error(String.format("file was %s", documentFile), e);
```

to this:

```
LOGGER.error(String.format("file was %s", documentFile), 
                printErrorStackTrace? e : null );
```

And then in my test method I put this:

```
appClass.setPrintErrorStackTrace( false );
```

... obviously we're told not to allow testing code to reach into app code ... but of course I could instead have use a method `getPrintErrorStackTrace()` in the condition clause... and then mocked that method in the testing code. But would that have been any less heretical?  We're also told not to add functionality just to help testing.

But my log now looks a lot cleaner...